# Controller with @Profile is not loading

Tags: spring-boot

I've created controller with @Profile("native-account"). But when I run the application, end point present inside that controller is not loaded.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/api/v5",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
@Profile("native-account")
public class Address {
    private final AddressService addressService;


    public Address(AddressService addressService) {
        this.addressService = addressService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(
            value = "get Address",
            httpMethod = "GET",
            notes = "Get address information",
            code = 200
    )
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/address",
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE},
            method = RequestMethod.GET
    )
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success")
    })
    @HttpsOnly
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public Address getAddress(@ApiParam String custonerId) {

        return addressService.getAddressDetails(custonerId);

    }
}
```

But I could see, other controllers under same package are getting load and able to see in console while app is starting. But above controller end point is not visible.
I really lost here. Can someone suggest me please?. do I need to configure anything else for this ?

Comment: Are you sure you start the app with this profile?

Comment: I want to start like that. I'm not sure whether I'm doing mistake here or not?. Could you please help me If I'm doing any blunder here?

Comment: again, do you start the app with the particular profile?

Comment: No. None of my controllers have **@Profile**. This is the new one.

Comment: As requested before do you actually start the application with that profile. If not the controller won't be loaded. Maybe you might wan to read up on what `@Profile` is and does and how to use Spirng boot to enable those profiles.